# Expression was too complex error in swift

Tags: ios, swift

The expression was too complex to be solved in a reasonable time. I considered breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions but, I got an error on Swift. How can I solve it?

Comment: post the example i figured that after you broke it up you aren't accounting for an optional or you're trying to manipulate a var and an optional var

Comment: If you post the full expression, we can work on breaking it down for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do what the error says, break your code up into multiple parts. Why? Because it was taking the compiler too long.